# How To Properly Sign And Deploy VSTO Addin

Tags: c#, vsto, clickonce, office-addins, excel-addins

I have developed a vsto excel addin.

this is what i do to deploy it on a new pc.

1. copy all the files to local computer/folder

here is my folder structure:
[image: Folder Structure]

then i added following info to registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\Bill Generator For Quickbooks]
"Description"="Bill Generator For Quickbooks"
"FriendlyName"="Bill Generator For Quickbooks"
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003
"Manifest"="file:///c:\Users\SiamIT-VMW7\Desktop\redist\Bill Generator For Quickbooks.vsto|vstolocal"
```

then when i run/open excel, it shows following warning window (as the file(s) is not signed). And if i click "install" it does and works as it should

[image: Unknown Publisher]

As i like to remove that warning i have signed the manifest and vsto file using mage utility. but excel throws following error if i try to run using signed version ?!?

[image: Manifest Error]

what i am missing here then? what is the correct approach to avoid that warning window?

thanks in advance

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some research i found the solution..

that error was showing as i sign both files (the manifest and the vsto) using maze -sign command. but that is not the correct procedure..

1st i need to sign the manifest file using maze -sign command

And then i need to sign the vsto file using maze -update command so that maze can add the signed manifest hash in vsto file so that it can be matched by excel.

here is the example command line codes to sign the manifest:

```
mage.exe -s "Bill Generator For Quickbooks.dll.manifest" -a sha256RSA -ch [My Certificate Hash] -csp "[My Certificate Service Provider]" -kc [My Certificate Key Container] -TimeStampUri [My Certificate Provider Timestamp URL]
```

And Here is the example command line codes to sign the vsto file using update command

```
mage.exe -u "Bill Generator For Quickbooks.vsto" -appmanifest "Bill Generator For Quickbooks.dll.manifest" -a sha256RSA -ch [My Certificate Hash] -csp "[My Certificate Service Provider]" -kc [My Certificate Key Container] -TimeStampUri [My Certificate Provider Timestamp URL]
```

and when i add this way signed files to the deployment it works nicely!

here is the screenshot how it looks like:

[image: Verified Publisher]

I posted my own answer with a thought that it may helps someone some day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see a standard dialog for ClickOnce installers when you try to install a non-signed application. To avoid such dialogs you need to sign the application and deployment manifests. They must be signed with a public/private key pair and signed using Authenticode technology. You can sign the manifests by using a certificate from the Windows certificate store or a key file.

> As i like to remove that warning i have signed the manifest and vsto file using maze utility.

`Maze` is not related to digital signatures. You need to sign your `ClickOnce` installer with a digital signature from any trusted vendor, see [How to: Sign application and deployment manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-sign-application-and-deployment-manifests?view=vs-2022) for more information.

Also you may find the [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) article helpful.

Comment: "Maze is not related to digital signatures", i am sorry sir, but i don't thinks that is a correct statment. Of course mage can be used to sign manifest, vsto even the exe file as well. Please check my posted answer.

Comment: Mage, but not Maze like stated in your post.

Comment: ah! my bad sir.. just a typo. please do pardon me. But as an expert like you should have catch that as well :)

Comment: I can't know all tools like Maze :)

Comment: i do apologize if i mean any offense, all i just tried to praise you that you have a sharp eye and lot of experience than me.. Please don't get me wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The first prompt is always shown by the VSTO system when an addin is installed and used for the very first time. Even if the certificate is trusted.

The second prompt is shown because the the certificates specified in the manifest/vsto/dll files don't match.

Comment: thanks for your reply, though following statement "The first prompt is always shown by the VSTO system when an addin is installed and used for the very first time. Even if the certificate is trusted.", because that warning/popup was showing as i was trying the adding from desktop, when i install the addin in program-files folder, that's pouup didn't showed.

Comment: The location does not matter. If you installed it once, VSTO will remember the certificate.

Comment: thanks for your reply, sorry to say again.. i did try on new machine.. fresh new (vm reset).. and it does not ask for it (popup)

Comment: Ah, yes, now that you mention it - I don't think is asks if the executable is in a folder that only an admin can write to. In that case, it is trusted right off the bat.  If it is one of the user-write-accessible folders, it will prompt.

Comment: that's right my dear sir! once again thanks for your answer, all the comments and time you passed on my matter.